External SD card write permission for an old app
I have a Samsung Galaxy A50 phone with Android 9 (I don't want to upgrade! Upgrade is not a matter of this question!) and an old file manager app of a great value (built not by me) that works just fine except it can't write to the external SD card inserted into the phone. A built-in app that came with the phone can write to the external SD card.
On the other hand, the same phone model with Android 11 allows this very app to write to external SD card using the same mounting point (/storage/ALPHANUMERIC-SD-CARD-ID).
I have read that the app has to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and this requires an access to the source code. This app wasn't built by me, so I can't change it.

Does it all mean that this behaviour was fixed in Android 11?
May be there are some hidden settings to enable external SD card write access?


If the app supports write access to the internal flash storage section /sdcard when it already has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. For historical reasons this permissions has the EXTERNAL in it's name even if it mostly used on Android devices before 10 to get access to the internal shared flash memory.
However even if an app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission it doesn't get automatic write access to the physical sd-card. For getting write access the user has to "confirm" that you want to give access to the external sd-card. Unfortunately this process isn't well documented and very unintuitive even for tech-savvy people:
If an app want's to perform a write command on a physical sd-card instead the system files app pops-up (not sure if the app explicitly has to start this permission granting step or if Android does this automatically).
In this opened files app you have to select the root folder of the physical sd-card and then select the "open" (or "select"?) button in the files app.
If you do so the files app is closed and Android returns to the app you want to use for writing to the sd-card. Now the app should have write access to the sd-card if there are not other obstacles:
Personally I have an Android 9 device I used a lot with an physical SD-card, formatted as portable. From my experience there is one factory you have not considered: the used file-system on the sd-card. sd-cards larger than 64GB usually come pre-formatted with exFAT file-system. This file-system became officially supported by Android  with Android 13. However a lot of manufacturer implemented exFAT support in earlier versions. My personal experience with my Lenovo Android 9 tablet was that this manufacturer implemented support was often non-functional when it comes to write access. In some firmware versions it worked, in other not.
Another possible obstacle are files and folders that have the "read-only" flag set. With that flag set (e.g. because the files have been extracted form a ZIP, TAR, or whatever archive) Android refuses to rename or delete them. Only very few apps are able to reset the read-only attribute on Android.
